# How to get all major versions of List or Library Item using C#?

Tags: list, development, document-library, versioning, version-history

I have document library which has over 100 items. Each item has over 30 to 40 major & minor versions. I want to **get only major versions of particular item** programmatically using C#.

```
foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
{
  foreach (SPListItemVersion itemVersion in item.Versions)
  {
    if (item.File.Versions.GetVersionFromLabel(itemVersion.VersionLabel) != null)
    {                                                        
      // Get only major versions of item here ????
    }
  }                                                    
}
```

Comment: could you please share the whole fucntion from start as I not able to get it.

Comment: What do you want to get ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just a small trick as mentioned below.

Sample Code :

```
foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
{
  foreach (SPListItemVersion itemVersion in item.Versions)
  {
    if (item.File.Versions.GetVersionFromLabel(itemVersion.VersionLabel) != null)
    {                                                        
      if((Convert.ToDouble(itemVersion.VersionLabel)%1) == 0)
      {
         //You can get all major versions here.
      }
    }
  }                                                    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the version label and check is the second part 0

```
string[] versionArray = itemVersion .VersionLabel.Split('.');
int minorVersion = Convert.ToInt32(versionArray[1]);
if (minorVersion == 0)
{
    //this is a major version
}
```

or you can check the reminder when dividing VersionId with 512

```
int modulo = itemVersion.VersionId % 512;
if (modulo == 0)
{
    //this is a major version
}
```